# Building a linear Power supply

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, schematics, lm317, linear-regulator

Being a poor student and a hobbyist, I've decided to build a power supply. For simplicity's sake, I've chosen a linear supply, build around 2 variable independent channels with 3 commonly used taps - 3.3, 5 and 12 volts. The taps are fairly straight forward, but I want to implement current limiting on my 2 independent channels. While scrolling through the datasheet for the LM317, I noticed they had exactly what I needed.

http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm117.pdf   - The circuit is on page 21.

The MJ4502 transistor is seriously outdated and thus, expensive. (~5
       on ebay, e/a!) I understand I want to pick something with similar
       specs, but am coming up empty. The closest I've found so far is the
       TIP147, which is rated for around half the current (10A continuous).
       I could parallel them with ballast resistors, but the only problem
       is they're darlington, where as I need a single transistor.

Or I could use a MOSFET. I only know the absolute basics of getting
       them to work for me, but I'd love to use one - an IRF3205, 10 for $2?
       that would be a dream budget-wise.

Am I better of paying extra for the originally spec'd part, or should I go with a MOSFET or substitute transistor?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246328/dealing-with-bundle-omnibus-list-of-questions-question-that-consists-of-rather-d

Comment: Compressed it down into one pressing question.

Comment: The IRF3205 is an N-Channel MOSFET. On the other hand the MJ4502 is a PNP transistor. The page 21 circuit would never work with this substitution. Using a P-Channel MOSFET might be made to work with some fiddling with the circuit.

Comment: Oops, you're right. How about the PNP compliment, the irf4905?

Comment: The part is referred to as an **External Pass Transistor**. Your essentially asking how to calculate or spec the part. See https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/3333 as a reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [NTE180](http://www.nteinc.com/specs/100to199/pdf/nte180.pdf) appears to be very similar to the [MJ4502](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/MJ4502-D.PDF).

Whether these can be found cheap enough is another matter.

But, you can probably use a much lower spec transistor for the circuit in question: -

[image]

If you use Farnell, mouser or digikey's search engines and look for a PNP transistor that has a minimum voltage rating of (say) 60 volts (100V for MJ4503), a current of (say) 10 amps (MJE4502 is 30 A) and an Ft greater than 2 MHz, then pretty much all PNPs you find are going to be suitable.

Come back when you find one.

Comment: NTE themselves make a http://www.nteinc.com/specs/original/MJ4502.pdf and is being sold http://www.newark.com/nte-electronics/mj4502/bipolar-transistor-pnp-90v/dp/33C5072 The ON Semi one too is being sold http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?vendor=0&keywords=MJ4502 What this question is missing is how much current he wants. Implicit in it (in the talk about paralleling) is that he might want 30A, but then again it looks he upvoted you so he's probably unsure what he wants.

Comment: Also he doesn't say what the input voltage for his supply is. Assuming it's really 35V as shown in the figure, that's a really wasteful way to get 3.3V-12V out as he wants. If his input is less, then there are more alternatives (at 30A) with 40V breakdown.

Comment: Finally, I'm glad you didn't get into redesigning the supply to work with a PMOS :D

Comment: Oh, and I hope he's into aluminum scraping or else we're going to see a heatsink cost question [for those ~700W] soon after he tries to build this [assuming 35V input and 30A, 12V output]. :D

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I checked digikey, and though this                http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/2STA2510/1026-2STA2510-CHP/2521315   might work.  100V breakdown, 25A rated, $1.25 in singles. As for the power dissipation, well, it's going to be a lot. I was actually looking at configuring multiple taps on the transformer to get the input voltage a lot closer to the output voltage.

Comment: @Ethan what's wrong with a 10A device - the design is only good for 5A - double check the hFE of the transistor you choose also - it needs to be as good or better than the MJ4502. The device you have chosen is also obsolete AFAICT

Comment: hFE of the 2STA fis spec'd for 40-80, where as the MJ4052 is spec'd for 25-100. Seems like it should work. I'm ok with it being obsolete - is that what the "chip outpost" thing is about? A TIP36C would work as well.

Comment: I noticed it said obsolete on the data sheet that's all. Yeah hFE looks ok.